# trigger result by column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let us consider a dataframe with numbers distributed between -1 and 1. In this sequence there are two boundaries that change the state of system: -0.5 and 0.5. If the system cross 0.5, it will maintain its position until the system passes the -0.5 (and the oposite). A visual example is given in the following dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0.3,-0.1,-0.8,-0.7,0.2,0.9,0.4,-0.1,-0.8], [None, None, None, -1,-1,-1, 1, 1, 1, -1]]).T
```

How can we compute *column* **1** without using a for loop?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set up your conditions:

```
c1 = (df[0].lt(-0.5) & df[0].shift().gt(-0.5)) | (df[0].gt(-0.5) & df[0].shift().lt(-0.5))
c2 = (df[0].lt(0.5) & df[0].shift().gt(0.5)) | (df[0].gt(0.5) & df[0].shift().lt(0.5))
```

Then use `np.select` and `ffill`:

```
df.assign(out=np.select([c1, c2], [-1, 1], np.nan)).ffill()

     0  out
0  0.1  NaN
1  0.3  NaN
2 -0.1  NaN
3 -0.8 -1.0
4 -0.7 -1.0
5  0.2 -1.0
6  0.9  1.0
7  0.4  1.0
8 -0.1  1.0
9 -0.8 -1.0
```

The one thing this approach *does not* handle is what to do if both thresholds are crossed in a single step.  For example, if you go from `-0.6` to `0.8`, this will just default to the first condition.  You may want to adjust the conditions based on your need, but this will get you started.